# ASP.net : Master page Javascript function not firing from every content page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

A sample of folders in my web application is as follows:

MyApplicationName
--> MasterPages/MasterPage1.aspx
--> Reports/Clients/ARReports.aspx
--> AboutUs/CompanyInfo.aspx
--> Javascript/General.js

I have added Print ImageButton to Master page MasterPage1.aspx. It has a JavaScript function onClientClick event:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnPrint" runat="server" 
                 ImageUrl="~/images/icons/print.gif" 
                 AlternateText="Print" OnClientClick='javascript:PrintContent("printable");this.blur();return false;' />
&#160;Print &#160;
```

The PrintContent function is in General.js file.

CompanyInfo.aspx and ARReports.aspx both have Masterpagefile = MasterPage1.
Now the issue is that the Print ImageButton in CompanyInfo.aspx is able to call the JavaScript function when clicked. However, in ARReports.aspx no JavaScript function is fired when clicked.

What could be the problem? The ImageButton is in Master page which refers to the JavaScript file which has the JS function. It is working for CompanyInfo.aspx, but if we go deep inside the folders, it is not working.

Comment: Could you please post some relevant code?

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors? Ensure ‘display a notification for every script error’ is turned on in IE options, or use another browser that allows you to open the JavaScript console. In general I would strongly avoid JavaScript-fuelled print links, and use a print stylesheet that hides the unwanted parts of the page instead.

Comment: Webpage error details

Message: Object expected
Line: 154
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:3093/applName/reports/clients/arreports.aspx

This is the error in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Page Load I add the JavaScript file dynamically, so that all pages can access it with ResolveUrl

```
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(CreateJavaScriptLink("~/javascript/General.js"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're not including General.js in your master page but ARE in CompanyInfo.aspx?

Can you show us where (in what file) and how (syntax) you're including General.js?

Comment: I checked the MasterPage and here is the code inside the head
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title id="htmlTitle" runat="server">ABC Company</title>
    

<link id="CSSglobal" runat="server" href="../css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/General.js"></script></head>
There is no reference to JS file in the Content pages